# reading a php file with javascript on the same domain

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is simple. I have a `read.html` on the domain and it has a `Javascript` code in it that will read a php file on the same domain.  I was able to get the code of another html file. But when I try to read a php file I only get what I see in the browser.

What I get as output:

> admin

What I want:

```
<?
echo "admin";
?>
```

Comment: php needs to be parsed SERVER side. Javascript is in/for the browser. Wont work out!

Comment: To elaborate a bit further you need some type of HTTP server with PHP installed in order to parse PHP on any host. If you're attempting to do this locally then you will need a tool like [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript, running in a browser, can only access data on a server in the same way that any other remote application can (with some additional limitations caused by it being run in a sandbox, since you don't want arbitrary websites to be able to run any old code on your computer).

Since web servers are usually configured to run PHP programs and serve their output to the client, it is the output that your JavaScript program can see. This is generally desirable, server side code often contains confidential business logic and data such as credentials that shouldn't be exposed to just anybody with a browser.

If you want the PHP source code then you will need to either:

- provide a different URL that serves the source code instead of running the program (the easiest way to do this is to copy the PHP into a `.txt` file)
- configure your server to serve the PHP script from where it is instead of running it